# How do I collapse rows on key id but keep unique measurements in a new variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
                                Federal.Area State Total_Miles
1                          Allentown, PA--NJ    NJ     1094508
2                          Allentown, PA--NJ    PA     9957805
3            Augusta-Richmond County, GA--SC    GA     6221747
4            Augusta-Richmond County, GA--SC    SC     2101823
5                             Beloit, WI--IL    IL      324238
6                             Beloit, WI--IL    WI      542491
```

I'd like to collapse the rows by `Federal.Area` but create and keep new variables which contain the unique `State` and unique `Total_Miles` such that it looks like this:

```
Federal.Area          State    Total_Miles State1 State2 Total_Miles_state1 Total_Miles_state2
   <fct>                 <fct>       <dbl> <fct>  <fct>              <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 Allentown, PA--NJ     NJ        1094508 NJ     PA               1094508          9957805
 2 Augusta-Richmond Cou… GA        6221747 GA     SC               6221747          2101823
 3 Beloit, WI--IL        IL         324238 IL     WI                324238           542491
```

I don't know how to collapse the variables `State` and `Total_Miles` into the same row, but as new variables keyed on `Federal.Area`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Code formatting is done with the backtick button not the single quote. On most keyboards, the backtick is found beside the number 1, on the same key as ~.

Comment: In your example it looks like you have two rows per Federal Area. Is this always the case? If not, what is your desired output when there are three or more rows for a Federal Area?

Comment: My apologies. This is my first time really using the site. I will try and edit now.   That is actually a good question and there are several instances of one `Federal.Area` in three `State`.  With that in mind the new dataframe should really have `State3` and `Total_Miles_State3`.  The end goal is that each unique Federal.Area (whether 2 or 3) is collapsed into one row with the corresponding `Total_Miles` assigned from the respective `State` as new variables.  I will use these new variables to calculate the percentage of 'Total_Miles' traveled in each state per `federal.area`.

Comment: Again, apologies. I am learning how to ask good questions. I should say the point of doing this is so that I can `join` this df to another one that keys on `Federal.Area` but I can't join them because the current df has multiple rows of `federal.area` whereas the other df has only one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `pivot_wider` from `tidyverse` to put your data into a wide format.

First would number the rows within each `Federal.Area` as 1 and 2. Then call `pivot_wider` which will append the

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Federal.Area) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Federal.Area, values_from = c(State, Total_Miles), names_from = rn)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Federal.Area [3]
  Federal.Area                  State_1 State_2 Total_Miles_1 Total_Miles_2
  <chr>                         <chr>   <chr>           <int>         <int>
1 Allentown,PA--NJ              NJ      PA            1094508       9957805
2 Augusta-RichmondCounty,GA--SC GA      SC            6221747       2101823
3 Beloit,WI--IL                 IL      WI             324238        542491
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Federal.Area = c("Allentown,PA--NJ", "Allentown,PA--NJ", 
"Augusta-RichmondCounty,GA--SC", "Augusta-RichmondCounty,GA--SC", 
"Beloit,WI--IL", "Beloit,WI--IL"), State = c("NJ", "PA", "GA", 
"SC", "IL", "WI"), Total_Miles = c(1094508L, 9957805L, 6221747L, 
2101823L, 324238L, 542491L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: That seems like it would work - any idea why I get this error?`Error: `...` is not empty.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `logical`

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: Completely fresh session - tidyverse is 1.3 and dplyr is 0.8.5. Still getting same error today

Comment: It was an annoying `vctrs` error.  See here for simple solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599249/why-am-i-getting-the-is-not-empty-error-mostly-when-using-pipe-and-basic

Comment: After I fixed that, your solution worked great!!! Will this solution work if I had say, three Allentown entries with a third state, like NY or something?

Comment: Glad to hear! Yes, it should work with more than 2 entries as long as in a similar format (for example, 3 "states" and 3 "total miles" per Federal Area).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Yes I even have Philadelphia which is technically in 4 states but the formatting is always the same.